# Strange behavior of HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

I found some strange behavior for hashmap In below class.

```
class Employee {

  private String a;
  private int b;

  public Employee(String a, int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((a == null) ? 0 : a.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + b;
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    if (a == null) {
        if (other.a != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!a.equals(other.a))
        return false;
    if (b != other.b)
        return false;

    return true;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Employee,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        map.put(new Employee( i + "", i), i + i);
    }
  }
}
```

When i am using new Employee( "", i) as key for storing data in map, it is working fine and resizing the map after 12th node insert. but on using
new Employee( i+"", i) as key, it is showing strange behavior, on adding 10th element by using this key, it resize map from 16 to 32 and on adding 11th element it is again resizing map from 32 to 64. 
Please help if you found any reason for this behavior.

Comment: How are you observing this behaviour? With a debugger? You're probably talking about the internal size rather than the actual number of entries in the map, right?

Comment: Yes, In debugging mode you can check that on adding 10th element it is resizing from 16 to 32...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason - new organization of HashMap in Java 8. When list inside particular bin becomes too long `HashMap` migrates that list to a Tree instead of a linked list - process called **treeifying**.

TREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 8 indicates that when within given bin there are 8 entries, then instead of linked list, given bin should store clashing values in binary tree (thereby changing search complexity with this bin from **O(n)** to **O(log n)**.

```
if (binCount >= TREEIFY_THRESHOLD - 1)
                treeifyBin(tab, hash);
```

Method  **treeifyBin** replaces all linked nodes in bin for a hash unless table is too small, in which case it resizes the table;

So in your case, you get 64 size (this code makes resize twice, increase tab size to 32 and that 64 (MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY)) :

```
if (tab == null || (n = tab.length) < MIN_TREEIFY_CAPACITY)
            resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@G_H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630136/g-h)  mentioned, I believe you are referring to the internal structure of the map, visible via a debugger.
A HashMap uses the hashCode() method to group objects in "buckets".

The hashCode() method you have overridden uses the value of the String member a. When a is "", its hash code is 0, and so the hash codes of the elements you are inserting are relatively closer to each other, than when setting a to a more meaningful string with a higher hash code.

For some reason (depends on how the hash buckets are exactly implemented), the HashMap object decides to enlarge its inner structure sooner when the hash code values are further apart.

For the elements you insert, take a look on their hash code values and it will make sense.

Comment: it's actually the "better spread elements" (as in ones where string `a == i + ""` ) which are causing the map to resize twice. As @Olga found this is due to **treefying** kicking off, but I would like to find out why did all of these values caused map to put them in one bin.

Answer (score 0):

I tried rewriting the has method of your code. With your implementation (Used Reflection to get map details),

```
Loop 0 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 1
Loop 1 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 2
Loop 2 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 3
Loop 3 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 4
Loop 4 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 5
Loop 5 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 6
Loop 6 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 7
Loop 7 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 8
Loop 8 : Capacity : 32, Factor : 24, Current Size : 9
Loop 9 : Capacity : 64, Factor : 48, Current Size : 10
Loop 10 : Capacity : 64, Factor : 48, Current Size : 11
Loop 11 : Capacity : 64, Factor : 48, Current Size : 12
Loop 12 : Capacity : 64, Factor : 48, Current Size : 13
```

After rewriting as below,

```
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    return prime * this.b;
}
```

Then the size increase is as expected,

```
Loop 0 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 1
Loop 1 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 2
Loop 2 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 3
Loop 3 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 4
Loop 4 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 5
Loop 5 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 6
Loop 6 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 7
Loop 7 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 8
Loop 8 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 9
Loop 9 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 10
Loop 10 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 11
Loop 11 : Capacity : 16, Factor : 12, Current Size : 12
Loop 12 : Capacity : 32, Factor : 24, Current Size : 13
```

Though i cannot explain with certainty, the below snippet from HashMap implementation indicates then the hash calculated value might increase the size of the Map.

```
void More addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int **bucketIndex**) {
    Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
    table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value, e);
    if (size++ >= threshold)
        resize(2 * table.length);
}
```